# asp.net Creating/Cloning a control with runat = server property using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runat

Is it possible to create/clone with javascript/jQuery a control with the property  `runat=server` dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. As runat="server" is used by server for generating html. If it is added on client server will not know it.